# Why does MSVC say a call to a virtual constexpr functional call operator does not result in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, constexpr, compiler-bug

I have a class that wraps an array. It inherits from an abstract base class defining one `virtual constexpr` method for the function-call operator. In the child class, I override said method and access the internal array:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class ContainerBase {
public:
    virtual constexpr const T& operator()(std::size_t i) const = 0;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Container : public ContainerBase<T, N> {
public:
    constexpr Container(std::initializer_list<T> data) {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), _items.begin());
    }
    constexpr const T& operator()(std::size_t i) const override {
        return _items[i];
    }
private:
    std::array<T, N> _items;
};

int main () {
    constexpr Container<int, 3> C = {2, -91, 7};
    constexpr int F = C(1);

    static_assert(F == -91);
}
```

Here is the [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/roe36E7P4).

To the best of my understanding, this is all legal code in C++20, which allows `virtual constexpr`. G++ 10.3 and Clang 12 both accept this as valid code, however MSVC 19.33 does not accept it, claiming that variable `F` is not a constant expression:

```
msvc_buggy_constexpr.cpp(29,21): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
msvc_buggy_constexpr.cpp(21,16): message : a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
msvc_buggy_constexpr.cpp(31,5): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
msvc_buggy_constexpr.cpp(21,16): message : a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
```

What gives? This looks like a compiler bug in MSVC to me. I would investigate further but MSVC on godbolt.org seems to be down right now.

I should add, the issue only presents itself when the function call operator method is `virtual` —when it is not, the issue does not occur.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: This is definitely an MSVC bug. Note that if you simply rename `operator()` to, say, `call`, and then do `C.call(1)` instead of `C(1)`, then MSVC accepts. There's nothing special about `operator()` in this case.

Comment: @Barry thanks for that further insight, that's very helpful. Now I have more information for when I eventually figure out where to file this as a bug report :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User @Barry agrees with me that it's definitely a bug in MSVC.

I've submitted [this bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-erroneously-claims-the-return-value/10184063).

Hopefully the issue gets resolved soon.

Thanks all for your comments and further insights, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure why putting `_items` in the base class will make MSVC accepts the code, maybe the virtual overloaded `operator()` without `_items` being in the base class make MSVC somehow thinks that it's not qualified for constexpr.

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class ContainerBase
{
protected:
    std::array<T, N> _items;
public:
    constexpr ContainerBase() : _items{} {};
    virtual constexpr const T& operator()(std::size_t i) const = 0;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Container : ContainerBase<T, N>
{
public:
    constexpr Container(std::initializer_list<T> data) : ContainerBase<T, N>()
    {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), this->_items.begin());
    }
    constexpr const T& operator()(std::size_t i) const override
    {
        return this->_items[i];
    }
};
```

Test on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s355Prjj3).

Another IntelliSense bug was spotted during this test: if `_items` were not initialized in the base class constructor (`_items{}`), IntelliSense will report this error, but the code can be compiled just fine:

> Error E0028: expression must have a constant value

Comment: Gosh that's so weird, good spot —all more helpful information for the MSVC dev team when they read my bug report!

Comment: So the IntelliSense error report about `_items` not being initialised has no bearing on the validity of the original bug report?

Comment: Yes, IntelliSense errors could be false-positive sometimes, often for new C++ features